# Can I connect Azure Active directory authentication to an already existing project?

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, blazor, .net-6.0

I have set up authentication with Azure Active Directory, in a new App Registration. I am following this (https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-blazor-server) tutorial to connect it to my project, but according to step 3 (Create the app using the .NET CLI), it looks like I have to set up a new project, is there any way to add it to my already existing Blazor server app?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.dotnet-msidentity/1.0.0-preview.1.21212.1

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I forgot. I ended up going with another solution though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making a new project where I did it from scratch, end then copied the relevant files and code into my existing project!

Answer (score 0):

To add authentication to an existing Blazor app with the Azure Active directory , the authentication mode must be changed to work or school accounts and the azure ad tenant domain must be added for connection purposes.

[image]

Some configuration changes in appsettings ,logindisplay.razor ,startup.cs are to be made to authenticate with azure ad.
Ex:
In appsettings.json ,

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": " ",
    "TenantId": " ",
    "ClientId": "  "
},
```

If app is already configured to be in required authentication mode , you can directly  register application in azure ad portal as you are already doing and add the callback url of your application.

Reference: [ASP.NET Core and Blazor Code Venture: Configuring Azure AD Authentication (vmsdurano.com)](https://vmsdurano.com/asp-net-core-and-blazor-code-venture-configuring-azure-ad-authentication/#serversideblazorauthenticationwithazuread)

You can refer [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-blazor-server/tree/main/WebApp-graph-user/Call-MSGraph) which help  authenticates users with  Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) and then acquires an Access Token for Microsoft Graph and calls the Microsoft Graph API.